# "Edit top 200 rows" not showing in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed a **SQL server management studio 2008** successfully. But I can't find the **Edit Top 200 rows** option when I right click on a table.

Does anybody know where I can find what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5):

I understand your question differently, as I have the same one. For me, the problem is that my Azure database doesn't have the **edit and view top row**, but when I connect to my Winhost one, they are there. I think that it is on the database's side, not your client. I am surprised that Azure doesn't support it, but I think that must be the case. I bet that the database you are connecting to is similar.

Comment: You can now, you need to have Manag. Studio 2014 and update hotfix:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx

File:
http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/SQL%20Server%202014/nosp/SQLServer2014_RTM_CU5_3011055_12_0_2456_/12.0.2456.0/free/480863_intl_x64_zip.exe

Answer (score 3):

"Edit row" is command for N rows. you can edit it here. Tools=> Options:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable most of the features you're used to for standard SQL Server, on Azure, you need to install the latest hotfix for SSMS 2104:

[Cumulative update package 5 for SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011055)

This will give you the Select Top 1000 Rows, Edit Top 200 Rows, Columns editor and more.